# Contacts from People API limited to 100 contats

Tags: google-people-api

I see 168 Contacts in my Contacts tab at https://contacts.google.com/.
Although, when I use the People API to retrieve them, using this link: https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,photos, I am only getting back 100 contacts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was not working is that by default there is a limit to the number of contacts you are getting back. You need to include a `pageSize` parameter in the URL to get all.

add `&pageSize=2000` to the one above.